# Is there a cleaner way to stay inside the bounds of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, optimization

I've got a two dimensional integer array that represents a map I'm using to track locations of objects in a game.  It gets modified by a procedural system that will change the numbers in there to place different objects.  I'll set the value of each Int as a 0,1 or 2.  Looks like this:

```
00010
00100
02120
21200
12000
```

Since the procedural step relies heavily on randomization, I want to put several checks in place that if the array location I'm trying to write is outside the bounds of the array, it'll fall back to the edge of the map instead of causing a fault.  e.g. I try to put an entry in [0,10] it'll default to [0,4].
Yes, I know that I should just be careful to make sure I never attempt to write outside the bounds of the array, but given other elements that won't happen every time.  A sanity check seems prudent.

The solution I came up with works, but it seems overly fiddly and long.  Is there a cleaner solution I'm unaware of?

Here's the code sample:

```
//Example of something randomly being written to the array
random r = new Random();
int xMax = field.GetLength(0);
field[mid(r.next(0,5), 0, xMax), 0] = 1; 

//Method for sanity bounds.
private static int mid(int target, int min, int max)
{
    //Target is the value we want
    //Min is the smallest possible value
    //Max is the largest possible value.

    if (target == min)
    {
        return min;
    }
    if (target == max)
    {
        return max;
    }
     if (target < max && target > min)
    {
        return target;
    }
    else if (target > max && target > min)
    {
        return max;
    }
    else if (target < min && target < max)
    {
        return min;
    }
    return min; //This shouldn't ever get trigger.  In here so compiler won't complain.
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but perhaps your last line in your method - `return min` - should throw an Exception if it's undefined/unexpected behaviour.

Comment: If you're accessing an invalid index you should *want* your program to crash so that you'll realize you have a bug and can fix it, rather than simply accessing the wrong array value and obscuring the problem, creating a bug that will be far harder to find and diagnose.

Comment: @DanPantry He doesn't need to do that.  He can just remove the whole thing in that case and just let the array indexer throw an index out of bound exception.

Comment: @Servy - I was speaking in general terms - if you're subduing a compiler error, chances are you *should* be throwing an exception :p

Comment: @DanPantry This isn't suppressing a compile time error.  It's throwing an exception.  and yes, I agree that an exception should be thrown here, but rather than creating a method to suppress an exception and then have it throw an exception, you can just *not suppress the exception in the first place* and not create a new method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
public int mid(int target, int min, int max)
{
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, target));
}
```

This function returns the maximum of the smaller value of the intended value and the maximum bound, ensuring that a valid value will be returned.

---

You can also use `%` in your accesses if you are using a rectangular 2-dimensional array:

```
array[index1 % array.length][index2 % array[0].length] = /* somevar */;
```

Comment: That's really slick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index to 'wrap' around the array as you described, this should work:

```
public void GetValidIndexForArrayFromRandomIndex(int index, string[] myArray)
{
    var upperBound = myArray.GetUpperBound(0);
    var lowerBound = myArray.GetLowerBound(0);

    while (index > upperBound)
    {
        index -= upperBound + 1;
    }
    while (index < lowerBound)
    {
        index += upperBound;
    }

    return index;
}
```

Or this should do what your code above does:

```
// We really only need to test the upper and lower bounds. 
// If target is greater than max or less than min, then return the bound that it crossed
if (target > max) return max;
if (target < min) return min;

// Otherwise, it's within the bounds, so just return target.
return target;
```

Or you could do it in one line:

```
return (target > max) ? max : (target < min) ? min : target;
```